# Can I use numbers in the name of my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have always named my rails app only with alphabets.

However, I want to start a new rails app now, and I'm thinking of giving it an alpha-numeric name.

I've checked around for conventions of naming a rails app ( If there is one ) can't get any.

Is there a convention for naming a rails app? ( maybe for the sake of configurations, etc... ) and if yes, what is the convention? Or, is it an `everything goes` world in this regards.

Thanks.

Comment: you use scaffold and check how rails creates that one for you, and you will get to know the conventions it follow... kind of backtracking.. :)

Comment: Okay, now, I at least know it can't start with numbers. when I tried, I get: `Invalid application name 10rados. Please give a name which does not start with numbers`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conventions are the same that apply to naming ruby classes, as after camelcasing app name should be valid ruby constant